# Mac os X - Capture Mail.app Notifications in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotification

I was trying to figure out a way how to capture notifications coming from - for example - the integrated mail.app. I was using the NSUserNotifications and acted as an observer but none of the Mail.app notifications were captured.

Is there a way in cocoa to capture NSNotifications coming from other apps? Especially the Mail.app?

Comment: I don't think there is a way unless you are listening for distributed notifications and Mail.app is actually sending them.

Comment: i just tried it but without success. Mail.app was showing an incoming new mail via Notification but this notification was not captures by my NSDistributed... Observer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although it is not possible to capture Mail.app notifications it is possible to use a NSMetadataQuery Live Search with a predicate bound to kMDItemType == "com.apple.mail.emlx" to start a live query including all mails. Everytime the user receives a new mail - the query will be updated!

This is not the answer to my question but this is my working workaround!